# Logging background process with parms as log name

Tags: bash, logging, sh

I am relatively new to shell scripting, and am trying to write a script that automatically creates a log based on the inputs to the script, but this requires the parsing of the arguments and (sometimes) the creation of directories.

I would like to log the first part of the script in case an error occurs, so have come up with a weird shuffling of log files.

```
#!/bin/bash
# Submission Example: sh task.sh 20 Illinois > /dev/null 2>&1 &

set -x 

tmpfile=$( mktemp $PWD/begin_log.XXXXXX )

exec > $tmpfile 2>&1

week=$1
area=$2

__proj_logdir=$PWD/${week}

mkdir -p ${__proj_logdir}

__proj_log=${__proj_logdir}/${area}.log

function resolve_logs {
  inter=$( mktemp $PWD/intermed_log.XXXXXX )
  mv $__proj_log $inter
  mv $tmpfile $__proj_log
  cat $inter >> $__proj_log
  rm -f $inter $tmpfile
}

trap resolve_logs EXIT

exec > $__proj_log 2>&1

echo "the rest of the script"

exit
```

My question is: Does there exist a built in command or option to allow this, or is there a better way to go about this?

Comment: Rather than mess with `nohup`. target a solution that works in crontab?  If you must persist with nohup, then it's not clear in your Q how `nohup` factors into the problem. You need to show us how you're testing and any error messages or other significant output you're getting. Good luck.

Comment: Thanks @shellter, in retrospect I can see that `nohup` does not factor in here -- I've removed the `nohup` requirement

Comment: Like I said in my first comment (now deleted), given your use case, I don't see much to improve on. Good luck.